# How To Scroll To A Desired Position In ScrollView?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, android-scrollview, android-search

I have an `EditText` with number input, a button and a `ScrollView` one below the other.

Inside the `ScrollView` I have a `Linear Layout` with vertical orientation and inside the `Layout` I have about 50 `TextViews` each with id 1,2,3,4....

What I want is that when the user enters a number in `EditText` and clicks the button,it should read which number is entered (say 28),then the `ScrollView` should scroll `Textview` with id 28 without disturbing the others.

I have no problem if I have to type the same code for each and every TextView even 500 times but it should be a working code like I mentioned above.

I have been trying to achieve this for a while without any success.Please Help!!!

Comment: try to use recycleView, refer to this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Comment: With that many items inside the scrollview and LinearLayout, RecyclerView is more better choice as suggested. It is created to serve this exact purpose. Your approach is very bad

Answer (score 1):

Find the view at that position in `LinearLayout` and scroll to that view

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                 scrollView.scrollTo(0, parentLinearLayoute.getChidAt(position).getBottom());
            } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace **Scrollview** and **Linearlayout** with **RecylerView**. And you can use **smoothScrollToPosition** to scroll to a particular position. I think this should be the best approach